# Python print split take char 5-10 for instance

Tags: python, printing, split

I want to split string that I have.

Lets say string is `hello how are you`.
I want to print only the `how are` (meaning start after hello and finish after are

My code for now just start after the hello, but print all the rest.
Want to avoid the `you`.

```
ReadJSONFile=JSONResponseFile.read() # this is the txt file with the line 
print ReadJSONFile.split('hellow',1)[1] # this gives me everything after hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use string slicing:

```
>>> s = "hello how are you"
>>> s[6:13]
'how are'
```

Comment: ...which is explained literally on the first page of the Python tutorial's language introduction: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 0):

Combine two `str.split` calls:

```
>>> s = 'hello how are you'
>>> s.split('hello', 1)[-1]
' how are you'
>>> s.split('hello', 1)[-1].split('you', 1)[0]
' how are '
>>> s.split('hello', 1)[-1].split('you', 1)[0].strip()  # remove surrounding spaces
'how are'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the start and end indices you can extract an [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) of the string by using the slice notation:

```python
str = 'Hello how are you"
# you want from index 6 (h) to 12 (e)
print str[6:12+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help: (Using index and slicing)

```
>>> start = h.index('hello')+len('hello')
>>> end =h.index('you')
>>> h[start:end].strip()
'how are'
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response,